# Reallocation logic

Tags: python, sql, logic

I am trying to see if a reallocation logic can be implemented in SQL , please let me know if this is doable in SQL or point me to the right place.

Table 1:

```
Store   Employee    Customer
1             A        1
1             A        2
1             B        3
```

The number of customers for each store is randomly distributed , some employees may have 30 customers while some can have as low as 1.

I am trying to see if within each store the customers can be re-allocated among employees

Eg:

```
Employee A has 30 customers
Employee B has 9 Customers
Employee C has 2 customers
```

I want to re-allocate to the following:
Minimum per employee as 10

```
Employee A has 21 customers
Employee B has 10 customers
Employee C has 10 Customers
```

THanks

Comment: Is absolutely any reallocation acceptable or is the goal to affect the minimum customers/employees possible? i.e. In your example, is 21/10/10 the only acceptable solution? Also, is it correct that customers/employees may not be moved across stores?

Comment: re-allocate randomly? A does not have to have the most number of customer or is it because from the original percentage?

Comment: Re-allocate randomly within employees from the same store.

Comment: @EdmCoff No 21/10/10 is not the only acceptable solution I am looking for but I want to make sure there is a balance among the employees.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my solution below with notes.  SQLServer 2012+ for the IIF otherwise use CASE

```
declare @mytable table (employee varchar(10), customers int)
declare @min smallint = 10
declare @divcustomers smallint 
declare @totalcustomers smallint 
declare @balance smallint 

insert into @mytable
values ('A',   18),
('B',       23),
('C',       13),
('D',       15)

-- get even allocation
select @divcustomers = sum(customers)/count(employee), @totalcustomers = sum(customers) from @mytable

-- re-initialise minimum otheriwse get the allocation
select employee, iif(customers< @min and @divcustomers > @min-1,@min,@divcustomers) customers
into #temptable
from @mytable t

-- update the balance to the most number of customers.. keeping the least to the minimum
update #temptable 
set customers = customers + (select @totalcustomers - sum(customers) from #temptable)
where employee = (
select top 1 employee from @mytable
order by customers desc

)

select * from #temptable

drop table #temptable
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the question wanted. I assume we are starting from the data in Table 1 of the question and trying to update it to meet the requirements. If we are really starting from something like the data you have in @mytable and selecting a summary of the solution, then I don't see why you wouldn't just do a query like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/313e3/1/0 .

Comment: the problem was about re-allocation but not equal re-allocation. of course i need to dissect the solution to better understand....  re-test your solution and put values A=5,B=50,C=2,D=1  and see the difference

Comment: I also didn't say anything about equal allocation, just that I think the question wanted you to use Table 1 to update Table 1 (i.e. actually reallocate the table, not just generate a report). Generating a reallocated report from an existing reallocated report is much simpler.

Comment: Just to clarify, I mean table 1 in the question which assigns the actual customers to employees, not just counts of employees to customers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that ignores the starting position completely. If the only criteria is to balance the customers to employees, all we care about it which employees are at which store, which customers are at which store, and assigning them evenly. Even the 10 limit doesn't seem particularly relevant. If we balance customers evenly, either there are enough customers to give each employee 10 or there aren't (in which case any other method would also fail).

I am assuming each store has at least as many customers as employees and that the same customer can't be assigned to multiple employees at the same store.

Here's the SQL server version ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f6e71/1/0)):

```
update tab 
SET tab.employee = thedata.employee
FROM 
(SELECT storeemp.store, storeemp.employee, storecus.customer
FROM
(SELECT store, customer, row_number() over (partition by store order by customer) as r
FROM tab
GROUP BY store, customer) storecus
join
(SELECT store, employee, row_number() over (partition by store order by employee) as r
FROM tab
GROUP BY store, employee) storeemp
on storecus.store = storeemp.store and (storecus.r-1)%(SELECT count(distinct employee) from tab where tab.store=storecus.store) = storeemp.r-1) theta
WHERE tab.store = thedata.store and tab.customer = thedata.customer
```

Here's the Oracle version (MOD instead of %):

```
update tab 
SET tab.employee = thedata.employee
FROM 
(SELECT storeemp.store, storeemp.employee, storecus.customer
FROM
 (SELECT store, customer, row_number() over (partition by store order by customer) as r
 FROM tab
 GROUP BY store, customer) storecus
join
 (SELECT store, employee, row_number() over (partition by store order by employee) as r
 FROM tab
 GROUP BY store, employee) storeemp
on 
 storecus.store = storeemp.store 
 and mod(storecus.r-1,(SELECT count(distinct employee) from tab where tab.store=storecus.store)) = storeemp.r-1) thedata
WHERE tab.store = thedata.store and tab.customer = thedata.customer
```

Comment: this is really painful and don't think you got the solution working to be honest.. the solution should be in a procedure/function form as a statement would not suffice.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Why doesn't this work? In what case would it fail? I listed the two big assumptions I am aware of in this. I included a sqlfiddle link to show the actual results and let you experiment with it.